# Como se puede hacer en VS Code una interfaz grafica para Java

Tags: java, vscode, interfaz-gráfica

He usado en Eclipse el WindowBuilder con JFrame para crear alguna interfaz y tengo la opción de hacerlo mediante la ventana **diseño** con la que insertas los elementos que quieres de una manera gráfica sin necesidad de escribir todo el código.
No hay algo así en VS Code? He estado buscando tutoriales pero creo que no son muy actuales y no consigo averiguar como se puede hacer actualmente. Además, los menús u opciones que suelen utilizar yo no las encuentro en mi VS Code como por ejemplo VB.Net, que debe ser algo parecido a lo que busco pero  no me aparece por ningun lado para crear un proyecto con eso.

Comment: te refieres a hacer visualmente una aplicacion swing?

Comment: Si, correcto. Como en Eclipse o netbeans que puedes arrastrar botones y otros y hacer un panel como quieras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No creo que puedas utilizar el DragaAndDrop de controles que te ofrece un IDE como Netbeans porque VisualCode, básicamente es un editor de codigo.

> Visual Studio Code es un editor de código optimizado con soporte para operaciones de desarrollo como depuración, ejecución de tareas y control de versiones. Su objetivo es proporcionar las herramientas que un desarrollador necesita *para un ciclo rápido de compilación y depuración de código* y *deja* los flujos de *trabajo más complejos para los IDE* con funciones más completas, como Visual Studio IDE .

Por otro lado te diría que chequees este link oficial para ver si te es de ayuda.
[GUI en VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-gui)
Saludos